# What is the relationship between shortest path and density for undirected graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Does the shortest path increase or decrease with graph density in undirected graphs? Or is there no clear relationship?

Comment: It is known that there is no upper bound for the chromatic number of a graph using graph density _alone_ (see [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895677900375)). Also, there is a classical result of Erdos that says that for $k\ge2$ there exist graphs with chromatic number and girth $>k$, so I would expect the answer to be that there is no clear relationship - but I am unsure. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an "[experimental mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_mathematics)" answer.

The following plot shows the [average path length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_path_length) vs. graph density in [Erdős–Rényi random graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) $G(50,p)$: 10 samples for each probability $p \in \{0.01,0.02,\ldots,1\}$.

[image: average path length vs. graph density in Erdős–Rényi random graphs]

Generally, we can see that graphs with higher density have shorter average path length (which is intuitive).

Note: Some of the graphs with close-to-$0$ densities have a small "average path length", but this is an anomaly of the definition (if there's no path, they have path length $0$).

Comments:

- It is likely that under different random graph models the behaviour is different (as, perhaps, it might be for, say, real-world networks).
- There are probably going to be contrived examples far away from the main curve, but the experimental results above suggest they will be relatively rare.

[The above figure was computed in [R](http://www.r-project.org/) using the [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) extension.  The relevant functions are  [`average.path.length`](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/shortest.paths.html) and [`graph.density`](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.density.html).  I also plotted the results using [tikzDevice](http://crantastic.org/packages/tikzDevice), making some manual edits.]